# UIPageViewController cache and swap view hierarchy for pages with similar content

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

My UIViewController has a UIPageViewController embedded in it.  The pager can contain anywhere from 5-38 pages (each page is an instance of a UIViewController subclass) depending on the situation.  I've noticed that depending how complicated I make the UI elements on each page, the app slows down considerably, and is very slow when swiping to go to the next page.

Here's the thing - the view on each page is identical, except for the values of a few UITextViews.  I am building the view in each page's viewDidLoad method each time viewControllerAtIndex is called for a new page.  I feel like there must be a way to re-use the same view for each page, and just swap the text values that are supposed to be different.  Can anyone describe a strategy to do this?

Like I said, every page has an identical view hierarchy except the values for some of the text, so I'm really just looking for a way to maintain one basic view controller per page, but cache the view hierarchy to be re-used on each page, and swap out some simple text values depending on page number.

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to mention in the original post is that I'm building my view programmatically because the number of elements on the page is dependent on choices the user made on previous screens.  i.e. there may be 5 TextViews or 10 TextViews, etc. depending on what the user selected on a previous screen (before coming to the UIPageViewController).  With that said, I do not believe an xib based approach will work because the initial layout is dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a xib based view, which you could pull out of the xib once, and keep a strong reference to it. In your controller's viewDidLoad, you could set its view to this xib base view, then populate the text view(s) with the proper text.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, thanks for your suggestion.  I forgot to mention that I have to build the view programmatically because the elements on the page are dynamic based on selections the user made on a previous screen (before coming to the set of UIPageViewController pages).  i.e. there might be 10 textviews on the page, or there might be 4, just depends what the user selected.  I'm not sure an xib based view would work in this case, but please correct me if I am wrong.